# VSCODE plugin programming: How to compound several commands in command history to make single undo/redo action?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing a vscode plugin to simultaneously comment out and duplicate a line. A key sequence of actions within the plugin (modulo several selections etc) is the following:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand("editor.action.commentLine");
vscode.commands.executeCommand("editor.action.copyLinesDownAction");
vscode.commands.executeCommand("editor.action.commentLine");
```

So this is fine and it works. The only problem is: the undo/redo history treats all these commands as separate operations... so I do the whole thing with a single keystroke, but if I want to undo, I have to hit Cmd+Z 3 times, which feels confusing.

How I instruct VSCode to treat a sequence of commands as a single "block" within the undo/redo history?

Comment: when you use a `TextEditorEdit` `editor.edit()` you can mark the operation to save an undo point. Program the action yourself and only set one call with undo point

Comment: @rioV8 Are you saying that I need to replace calls to `executeCommand` with my own implementations thereof? Do you mind giving an example?

Comment: if you write this modification yourself you only need one `editor.edit()` call

Comment: Ok well  i have no idea how I would implement something as complex as `editor.action.commentLine`, so if you're suggesting that I re-implement that on my own, I guess I'm out...